# not able to prepend font icon to my list elements

Tags: html

I am not able to prepend font icon to my list items,i have used simple script to do that,don't know where it went wrong

html:

```
<html>
<head>        
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<script>
 $( document ).ready(function() {
     $( ".our_vision_page_content ul li" ).prepend( "<i class='fa fa-circle'> </i>" );
 });
</script>
</head>

   <body>
   <div class="our_vision_page_content">
       <ul>
        <li>We are providing zero % interest loan facility, along with RO schemes to purchase Ro purifier systems.</li>
        <li>Price at affordable rates with no compromise on quality. Cost is spared from advertisement.</li>
        <li>From the last year, We are installing our products in each houses in villages through demonstration and educating villages peoples regarding safe drinking water.</li>
        <li>Any RO company in the country cannot install RO systems in houses of villages. Because in village houses there will be no facilities for water tap and over head tank in these houses.</li>
     </ul>
   </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: check out your code you are not closing the i tag <i class='fa fa-circle'> </i>

Comment: what problem missing jquery plugin or in completed tag?

Comment: @Nag check my fiddle and ans its comlately work.you need to just add jquery CDN for run jquery and style

Comment: @Nag! Have you tried this?
http://stackoverflow.com/a/34762626/3710908

Answer (score 1):

Why use jQuery/JavaScript if we can achieve this with simple CSS3?

Try this:

```
.our_vision_page_content ul li:before {    
font-family: 'FontAwesome';
content: '\f10c';
margin:0 5px 0 -15px;
color: #f00;
}
```

Comment: This would make sense unless the poster has a specific reason for needing the element injected in. But I wouldn't see why he would - this is how I would roll.

Answer (score 1):

I use your own code to make this JSFiddle :

```
   <div class="our_vision_page_content">
       <ul>
        <li>We are providing zero % interest loan facility, along with RO schemes to purchase Ro purifier systems.</li>
        <li>Price at affordable rates with no compromise on quality. Cost is spared from advertisement.</li>
        <li>From the last year, We are installing our products in each houses in villages through demonstration and educating villages peoples regarding safe drinking water.</li>
        <li>Any RO company in the country cannot install RO systems in houses of villages. Because in village houses there will be no facilities for water tap and over head tank in these houses.</li>
        </ul></div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/azhqdf83/2

your code add the `i` tag, i think you forgot to include the jQuery library

Comment: i have included jQuery library! no problem with that

Answer (score 0):

```js
 $( document ).ready(function() {
     $( ".our_vision_page_content ul li" ).prepend( "<i class='fa fa-circle'> </i>" );
 });
```

```css
ul
{
    list-style-type: none;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>        
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
</script>

</head>

   <body>
   <div class="our_vision_page_content">
       <ul>
        <li>We are providing zero % interest loan facility, along with RO schemes to purchase Ro purifier systems.</li>
        <li>Price at affordable rates with no compromise on quality. Cost is spared from advertisement.</li>
        <li>From the last year, We are installing our products in each houses in villages through demonstration and educating villages peoples regarding safe drinking water.</li>
        <li>Any RO company in the country cannot install RO systems in houses of villages. Because in village houses there will be no facilities for water tap and over head tank in these houses.</li>
     </ul>
  </div>
   </body>
  </html>
```

Use this is complately work.